# How to reset Apache airflow dag cache in the backfill?

Tags: python, airflow

I started a backfill job in airflow and ran into an issue with the dag definition half way through the backfill.

The code changed required a tiny tweak to an export file format in a python operator to include quotes.

No changes were made to the names or numbers of tasks.

When I resume my backfill, the old code is still being executed, however when I execute updates in present time the new dag code is used.

Is there a way I can have the backfill process use the new dag code too?

Comment: Are you using the `--donot-pickle` option in your backfill command? The default in the airflow configuration template is to have workers use there own version of the code. You probably have to restart your workers to get them to see the live code.